# HBO Go Termination of NPAPI plugin support

Tags: video, streaming

I'm at a loss. HBO GO hasn't ever been consistent for me or anyone I know (16.04). Are there solutions to streaming HBO GO without using HBO Now? I've tried the Firefox route to no avail.

Comment: As this is not a package in the Ubuntu repos, you have to contact HBO regarding Ubuntu support. The more complaints / requests HBO receives the more likely they will support Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://help.hbogo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204870417-Is-HBO-GO-supported-on-Linux-

> HBO GO/MAX GO is not accessible on the Linux platforms, including the Ubuntu & Tizen OS.

You have to complain to HBO and ask them to support Linux.

Submit a request here - https://help.hbogo.com/hc/en-us/requests/new